# Anacondaに同梱されてないライブラリを入れるには？

Tags: python, windows, python3, anaconda

私はWindowsなおかつ、Anacondaという汎用的なPython処理系を導入しています。
でも、Anacondaには入っていないライブラリもありますヨネ。（例えば[Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)や[pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news)とか）
そのようなライブラリの導入方法が知りたいです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows かつ Anaconda 環境の場合の一般的な質問のようなので、一般的な方法を紹介します。

#### 1. [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/) に無いか確認する。

Anaconda は、公式では配布していないパッケージを第三者が配布するための仕組みとして、Anaconda Cloud を運営しています。有名なライブラリであれば、誰かが既にパッケージとして配布してくれているかもしれません。

たとえば今 Kivy で検索すると https://anaconda.org/krisvanneste/kivy が出てきます。多少古いですが、Windows 64 bit、Python 2.7 向けの Kivy 1.8.0 でよければここからインストールできます。サイトにも書いてあるように `conda install -c krisvanneste kivy` を実行すれば良いです。

Pygame の場合も同様に調べると、 https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame や https://anaconda.org/tlatorre/pygame など、複数候補が見つかります。この場合は、対応しているプラットフォームの種類やライブラリのバージョン、今までのダウンロード数、[外部 Q&A サイトでの反応](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19636480/5989200)などを見ながらどれが良いか選ぶことになります。Windows の場合、前者が良さそうですね。

#### 2. 公式ホームページを確認する。

Anaconda Cloud に無ければ、残念、ショートカットはできないようです。まずは公式のインストール方法が公開されていないか確認し、されていればそれに従いましょう。

インストール方法は大抵、公式ホームページのトップから "Download" や "Installation" などのリンクを辿った先に書いてあります。たとえば Kivy の場合、最近はちゃんと Windows 向けのインストール方法が https://kivy.org/#download から辿れるリンク先で解説されています。Pygame に関しても [http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame Installation](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation) の下の方で解説されています。

#### 3. 第三者がインストール方法を提供していないか確認する。

公式ホームページが Windows 向けのインストール方法を提供していない場合、いくつかの選択肢があります。

- 第三者が Windows 向けに改造して配布していないか探す。ただし、バージョン違いやセキュリティにより一層気をつける必要があります (Anaconda Cloud の場合もある程度セキュリティは意識した方が良いです)。Anaconda の中で処理する場合は外部ライブラリのバージョンを Anaconda が自動的に調整してくれる仕組みがあるのですが、これが利用できなかったりするので、Python の仮想環境を作るなどして調整する必要があるかもしれません。
- そのライブラリの Q&A サイトやフォーラム、メーリングリストなどで、Windows 向けのインストール方法が無いか聞いて、教えてもらう。
- ソースコードから自分で Windows 向けにビルドする (初級者にはオススメしません)。

Comment: WIndows 以外の場合の補足、ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 念の為コメントしますが、これらはすべて Windows 環境下の話です。

Comment: でも、Python3はなぜか対応していないみたいですから大丈夫ですよ。

Answer (score 2):

[このサイト](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)にアクセスして、
自分が使いたいライブラリの名前を探して、自分の環境にあったwhlファイルをダウンロードしましょう。
そしたらPowerShellなり、コマンドプロンプトなりでwhlファイルをダウンロードしたフォルダが有るところへ移動して、

```
python -m pip install ダウンロードしたwhlファイル名.whl
```

って入力してエンターを押しましょう。
あとは指示に従うだけでOKですよ。

追記:前に書いたのがすべてのユーザーにインストールしている場合のほうだったので少し修正。
一人のユーザーにインストールすること前提だったんですね…。

Comment: ほんとうはWindows限定なんだけど、誰か見てくれること信じて、残しておきます。